# como llamar el siguiente nodo desde Firebase!

Tags: firebase, real-time

Debo anotar que esos Id son de FirebaseAuth y no son propios.
he leído que el Datasnapshot es el que trae esto. pero siempre me marca null.

ajunto imagen.

y los nodos que necesito obtener son los finales! "0" y "1"

Muchas Gracias!!!

[image: RealTime Database]

Comment: podrias adjuntar el código que te trae null desde esta referencia ?

Comment: ya lo encontré! 
Estaba utilizando el datasnapshot con getUid() y entonces hacia alusión a mi mismo id, cuando lo que necesitaba tomar datos de otro id diferente y cuando hacia alusion al mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid(). me tomaba era mi propio id!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

esta fue solucion al error
porque siempre tomaba era el id con el que iniciaba sesion y no el del objeto que necesitaba.....

```
            DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
            Query lastQuery = databaseReference.child("Aliados").orderByKey().equalTo(aliadoId);
            lastQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Log.d("User key", child.getKey());
                        Log.d("nombre", child.child("nombre").getValue().toString());
                        Log.d("User val", child.child("Ubicacion").getValue().toString());
    
                        String key = child.getKey();
                        String location = child.child("Ubicacion").child(key).child("l").getValue().toString();
                        String nombre = child.child("nombre").getValue().toString();
    
                         aliadoLatLong = new AliadoLatLong(key, location, nombre);
                        dataSnapshot.getValue(AliadoLatLong.class);
                        mExtraOrigin = location;
    
                        requestActivity = new DetailRequestActivity();
                        requestActivity.setNombreAliado(nombre);
                    }
                }
    
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    //Handle possible errors.
                }
    
            });
```

Muchas Gracias!